# Localize lightweight date picker in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

On Android and on iPhone, the Codename One lightweight picker always is in English, like in the following screenshot. How can I localize it in Italian (or in any other language used by the smartphone user)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can localize "Cancel" and "Done" in the resource bundle to replace those two labels. The month values are a bit more problematic as they are taken from `SimpleDateFormat` which doesn't have an easy path for localization. We should probably use the same localization conventions as used by the `com.codename1.ui.Calendar` class. I think this is something we can track via the issue tracker.